# Post multiple variables php

Tags: php

i'm making a shopping cart and need to post two things to the cart.php page FROM the detail.php page. I need the user to give an input (quantity) which is done by:

```
<form>
     <input type="number" name="Quantity" min="1" max="99">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And i am also collecting the product ID from another page done by

```
$pid = $_POST['productid2'];
```

I need to send them both in one click to the `cart.php` page so i can then add them to the database and then `cart.php` will show all items from the database in the cart.

**Edit:** I need to send `$pid` and the user's input to the `cart.php` page. Thanks.

For clarification i can get the quantity, i just don't know how get the `$pid` to the next page.

Comment: set it as session. or you can use this method `?id=$pid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hidden field to your form to send the $pid

```
 <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?= $pid ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data using php within the form:

```
<form method="post" action="cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php $_POST['pid'] ?>">
    <input type="number" name="Quantity" min="1" max="99">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But, when you refresh the second page, you will lose your `$_POST['pid']`.

You can set it first in a session variable:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (empty($_SESSION['pid']) && !empty($_POST['pid'])) {
        $_SESSION['pid'] = $_POST['pid'];
        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SESSION['pid'])) {
        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    }#if
?>
```

And use adjust the html form a little:

```
<form method="post" action="cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php $pid ?>">
    <input type="number" name="Quantity" min="1" max="99">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This way, you will keep the PID even the page reloads.